# $F[x]/(x+1)\cong F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I already know that if $F$ is a field and $F[x]$ is a polynomial ring with one variable, then $F[x]/(x)\cong F$. But as $F[x]$ is PID, $x+1$ is irreducible, $F[x]/(x+1)$ is also a field. I wonder if $F[x]/(x+1)\cong F$. I think the answer is negative but how can I show?

Comment: Define a ring homomorphism $F[x]\to F$ as $1\mapsto 1$, $x \mapsto -1$. Clearly, it is surjective. Show that its kernel is the ideal $(x+1)$.

Comment: This is true more generally, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927762/proving-that-fx-fx-cong-f-alpha).

Comment: $F[x]/(x+1)$ can be seen as the [Congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) $(\mod (x+1))$, so for any $f(x)\in F[x]$, let $f(x) = g(x)(x+1) + h$, we have $f[x]\equiv h ( \mod (x+1) )$. as $h$ can be anything in $F$, $F[x]/(x+1) \cong F$

Answer (score 1):

The morphism $F[x]/(x+1) \rightarrow F, \; x+(x+1)\mapsto (-1)$ is an isomorphism of fields, which can be checked very easily.